# Convert NodeJS agenda ready event anonymous function to normal function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, agenda

I'm using NodeJS Agenda module for job scheduling. 
In agenda there is an event 'ready'

```
module.exports = function(agenda) {
 agenda.define('test', function(job, done) {

});

agenda.on('ready', function() {
 agenda.every('*/5 * * * * *', 'test');
 agenda.start();
});

}
```

Here inside on ready event I'm using an anonymous function, but I don't want to use anonymous function, want to create a normal function.

for example

```
module.exports = function(agenda) {
 agenda.define('test', function(job, done) {

});

 agenda.on('ready', startJob());

}


function startJob(agenda) {
 agenda.every('*/5 * * * * *', 'test');
 agenda.start();
}
```

but it's not working getting

```
Cannot read property 'start' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're directly invoking the function without passing the agenda-object. One way to solve this, would be:

`agenda.on('ready', () => { startJob(agenda); });`

Or if you want to pass the startJob-function as the callback, you'd need to bind the agenda-object to it:

`agenda.on('ready', startJob.bind(this, agenda));`

Comment: Thanks for help but if I do agenda.on('ready', startJob(agenda) ) I'm still passing agenda object here but why it's not working ?

Comment: Because an event handler requires a callback-function, you cannot pass an already called function -> check out https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener

Comment: Now If I write above code module.exports = function(agenda) {
 agenda.define('test', function(job, done) {

});
 agenda.on('ready', startJob(agenda));
 
 function startJob(agenda) {
  agenda.every('*/5 * * * * *', 'test');
  agenda.start();
 }
} I just defined startJob inside module.exports function, it's working, how you will explain it?